# Error with select in Stored Procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure to be called when a button (Copy) is clicked on my front end application, I seem to be having a problem with the select statement after the #TestData table. Can some please help by pointing out the error.

```
Create Procedure CopyRates
@Period_id INT
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #TestData (Period_id int, Evo_StockLink int, Evo_itemCode    varchar(50), Evo_Description varchar(50), UnitRate float, MinRate float, RateBeforeSevenDays float, RateAfterSevenDays float)

INSERT INTO #TestData (Period_id, Evo_StockLink, Evo_itemCode ,Evo_Description, UnitRate, MinRate, RateBeforeSevenDays, RateAfterSevenDays)
VALUES
SELECT  Period_id, Evo_StockLink, Evo_itemCode ,Evo_Description, UnitRate, MinRate, RateBeforeSevenDays, RateAfterSevenDays

From [ZS_CS_EVO_Integration].[dbo].[rates]

Where Period_id = @Period_id

INSERT INTO rates(Period_id, Evo_StockLink, Evo_itemCode ,Evo_Description, UnitRate, MinRate, RateBeforeSevenDays, RateAfterSevenDays)
   SELECT Period_id +1, Evo_StockLink, Evo_itemCode ,Evo_Description, UnitRate, MinRate, RateBeforeSevenDays, RateAfterSevenDays
   FROM #TestData
END
```

Comment: What's the error exactly?

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl The error is: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CopyRates, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.

Comment: The first insert fails.. when using insert.. select you don't need VALUES (this is only used for hardcoded values).

Comment: @EduardUta There is values already in the database which need to be copied (Last 3 lines) once a year and the rates changed accordingly (Front end app).

Comment: Nope, you missed my point. I said that you can't use VALUES keyword on an insert statement when the rows come from a select statement. An you have this error in the first insert statement ..  INSERT INTO #TestData ()
VALUES
SELECT  Period_id,...

Comment: Yep, remove "values" from your insert into ..... select ....

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO #TestData (Period_id, Evo_StockLink, Evo_itemCode ,Evo_Description, UnitRate, MinRate, RateBeforeSevenDays, RateAfterSevenDays)
-- remove this**VALUES** 
SELECT  Period_id, Evo_StockLink, Evo_itemCode ,Evo_Description, UnitRate, MinRate, RateBeforeSevenDays, RateAfterSevenDays

From [ZS_CS_EVO_Integration].[dbo].[rates]
```

actually you don't need the #TestData temp table, you can insert direclty into rates table from [ZS_CS_EVO_Integration].[dbo].[rates]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
* 
INTO temp_Rates
FROM rates 
WHERE Period_Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Period_Id FROM rates ORDER BY Period_Id DESC)

INSERT INTO rates 
SELECT Period_id +1, 
Evo_StockLink, 
Evo_itemCode,
Evo_Description, 
UnitRate, 
MinRate, 
RateBeforeSevenDays, 
RateAfterSevenDays
FROM temp_Rates
```